# How can I see the revision of mobile web?

Tags: support, mobile-web

For example, when writing this question, the revision of the desktop web is 2018.1.24.28549, as shown in the image below. You can easily find this information by looking at the bottom right corner of a page.

[image: 1]

SE officials also respond to bug reports like

> Starting next build (rev xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx), this bug is fixed.

But where's the revision for mobile web?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same as the desktop revision.

Comment: So you mean I need to navigate to the desktop page to see the revision?

Comment: @iDebug If we didn't put it in the UI somewhere, which I assume we didn't... yes.